# Calling two functions onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing the users username in local storage. If the user updates the username I want to remove the previous name from local storage and update it. I am trying to call a clear function before the display function but it is not working.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Users from "./UserPageComponents/Users";
import "./UserPageComponents/userpage.css";

const UserPage = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [userText, setUsertext] = useState("");

  const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
    setUsertext(e.target.value);
  };
  const clear = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  };
  const addUser = () => {
    const newUser = {
      text: userText,
      id: Math.random() * 100,
    };
    setUsers([...users, newUser]);
    setUsertext("");
  };

  submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    clear();
    addUser();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("userStored");
    if (data) {
      setUsers(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("userStored", JSON.stringify(users));
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form className="userpage-form">
        <div>Profile</div>
        <div className="flex">
          <div>User Name:</div>
          <input type="text" value={userText} onChange={inputTextHandler} />
          <button onClick={submit}>Add</button>
          <button onClick={clear}>delete</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Users users={users} setUsers={setUsers} />
    </>
  );
};

export default UserPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you explicitly set the `localStorage` value back again. You have to remove this `useEffect()` (without a depndency array it is called on every re-render):

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("userStored", JSON.stringify(users));
});
```

or do this in your `clear()`:

```
setUsers([]);
```